# what is fp and tn in word sense diasiambiguation in calculating precision and recall

Tags: python-3.x, nlp

I want to calculate precision and recall for word sense disambiguation. Naturally, for that I need to calculate tp, tn, fp and fn. I know tp is the number of documents that the tag of the test sentences equals to the tag of the classifier and fn is the number of documents that the tag of test sentences is not equal to the tags that the classifier found. But what is tn and fp? I can't see any other case more than the two cases I described above. For example my test sentence is as like as below:

fist sentence: word1 word2 word3 word4 tag1
second sentence: word1 word2 word3 word4 tag2

If my classifier finds the correct tag which is equal to the tag in sentences, it's tp unless it's fn. So what is tn and fp?

Comment: The standard definition of specificity and sensitivity works best w/ binary classifiers. See [this answer](http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/51296/how-to-calculate-precision-and-recall-for-multiclass-classification-using-confus) for a generalization for multiclass situations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you're too caught up in the words "positive" and "negative".

Let's consider your sentence classification is binary: it's either a statement or a question.

[image: Binary Classification]

So, here, we are considering Statement = positive; Question = negative:

- True Positive = Your classifier predicted Statement and it is a statement.
- False Positive = Your classifier (falsely) predicted Statement (positive) when in fact the sentence is a question.
- False Negative = Your classifier (falsely) predicted Question (negative) when in fact the sentence is a statement.
- True Negative = Your classifier predicted the sentence to be a question and it is a question.

> I know tp is the number of documents that the tag of the test
>   sentences equals to the tag of the classifier

No, that is (tp + tn). Number of statements correctly predicted + Number of Questions correctly predicted.

> fn is the number of documents that the tag of test sentences is not
>   equal to the tags that the classifier found

That is (fp + fn). Number of statements you tagged as questions + number of questions you tagged as statements.

Again, "positive" and "negative" are just classes.

Comment: thanks for your answer. But how should I calculate them when there is more than 2 classes. I have about 50 files of ambiguous words. some of them have 3 senses. some 4 and some 5.

Comment: For Multiclass classification, have a look [here](http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/21551/how-to-compute-precision-recall-for-multiclass-multilabel-classification) (2nd answer), and [here](http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/51296/how-do-you-calculate-precision-and-recall-for-multiclass-classification-using-co).

But, it looks like yours is a multi-label classification problem which I am not too familiar with. In any case, take a look at the evaluation section of [this survey paper](http://people.oregonstate.edu/~sorowerm/pdf/Qual-Multilabel-Shahed-CompleteVersion.pdf).